# git-svn - #object# doesn't exist in the repository at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4706

Tags: git, git-svn

on

```
git svn dcommit
```

it starts commiting and then I get this

```
A   spec/controllers/authenticated_system_spec.rb
A   spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb
A   spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
A   spec/fixtures/users.yml
A   spec/helpers/users_helper_spec.rb
A   spec/models/user_spec.rb
A   vendor/plugins/haml/init.rb
A   vendor/plugins/restful_authentication
7235d9150e8beb80a819923a4c871ef4069c6759 doesn't exist in the repository at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4706
Failed to read object 7235d9150e8beb80a819923a4c871ef4069c6759 at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 570
```

any ideas how one goes about fixing this one?

tried inspecting with `git fsck --full` but git repo and all git commands seem to work fine just can't dcommit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you create **[submodules](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html)** in your Git repo ?
This [blog post](http://de-co-de.blogspot.com/2009/02/git-svn-and-submodules.html) seems to mention that as an issue.

> As of Jan 2009 `git-svn` does NOT work with submodules.
>   There is no good way to map submodules to svn and the perl script that implements git-svn just bombs when doing `git svn dcommit`.
>
> You need to go back and rewrite history.
>   You should be able to use `git commit --amend`.

```
$ git tag bad mywork~5
$ git checkout bad
$ # make changes here and update the index
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --onto HEAD bad mywork
```

Comment: yep did a git clone into the plugins dir, once removed commited fine.

Answer (score 14):

I had this same problem (where I had done a git clone and I'm using git svn).  Here's the command I used to remove the submodule:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter \
'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/the/formerly/misbehaving/module'
```

I found this wonderful solution on this [blog](http://ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2011/06/quick-trip-panic-room)

Comment: This worked fine for me. It also happend to me right in the middle of many commits, so I followed [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-code-hosting/4KZZf39Mdzk) first.

Comment: Life saver. I had it happen in the middle of finalizing transition of my team to git, when last merges between svn and git were made - and then suddenly a submodule appeared out of nowhere...

Answer (score 3):

This method does essentially the same as the accepted answer from @VonC but is expanded to make it easier to follow.

### The situation

This is the error I was getting when issuing `git svn dcommit`

```
#object# doesn't exist in the repository at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 5305
Failed to read object #object# at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 922
```

I had a number of commits in git that I was attempting to push upstream, and`#object#` was the SHA1 hash id of one of those commits `2d061be916dc4c2d54eed7b169f1dd80ecf04bc4` in my case.

I had included several other git repos from another sources into my project tree.  While I hadn't explicitly added them as git submodules I did `git add <existing_repo_path>`. git notices the .git file and adds `existing_repo_path` as a special case directory (i.e. as a submodule).  These directories are the herring bones that cause `git-svn` to choke.

### To Fix

```
find . -name .git
```

This will find any directory that was added as a submodule.

```
./.git   # Expect this one
./path/to/submodule1/.git
./path/to/other/submodule/.git
```

Remove the special directories from git while leaving the files on the filesystem:

```
git rm --cached ./path/to/submodule1 
git rm --cached ./path/to/other/submodule
```

Rename or delete the `.git` files from the submodule directories.  Renaming the `.git` files offers a little bit of protection since you could revert back.

```
mv path/to/submodule1/.git path/to/submodule1/dot.git
mv path/to/other/submodule/.git path/to/other/submodule/dot.git
```

If you had explicitly added submodules you may need to remove the `.gitmodules` file at the root of the repo. You should probably edit this file first to check if there is anything in it you want before removing it.

```
git rm .gitmodules
```

The submodule directories can now be added back into git and will be treated as ordinary subtrees (i.e. no longer submodules or special case directories).

```
git add ./path/to/submodule1  ./path/to/other/submodule
```

Commit these new files.

```
git commit -a -m "Changed submodules to ordinary directories"
```

The head of the git repo is now good.  But git-svn will still choke because it will attempt to create versions from the git history.  This means the git history needs to be changed.  My approach is to squash all of the git commits made since the last successful `git svn dcommit` into a single commit.  That way the new single commit will contain only the current head and not the troublesome 'submodule' versions.

To find the last successful svn commit use:

```
git svn log -n 1 --show-commit
```

I get something like:

```
r2917 | 094ed52 | rue | 2015-12-04 15:39:58 +0000 (Fri, 04 Dec 2015) | 2 lines
<commit message>
```

The output shows the SVN number (`r2917`) followed by the equivalent git commit id (`094ed52`)

Next start an interactive rebase of all the versions since this commit:

```
 git rebase -i 094ed52
```

This will open an editor with something like this:

```
pick 16b5fcc Changed submodules to ordinary directories
pick c964dea Some changes
pick 06cf8ee Added some things
pick 094ed52 Some other changes
```

`pick` means keep this commit, `squash` means include these changes into the next commit.  Replace all 'pick' with 'squash' except the first line.

```
pick 16b5fcc Changed submodules to ordinary directories
squash c964dea Some changes
squash 06cf8ee Added some things
squash 094ed52 Some other changes
```

Save and exit this file and you should get a new single commit.

```
git svn dcommit
```

Now works!

Comment: Another very simple way to add directories that contain a Git repository as ordinary directories instead of submodules is `git add ./path/to/submodule1/*` (note the `/*` at the end). I wish there would be a way to avoid/turn off the automatic creation of submodules by `git add` completely.