# git svn dcommit not work

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I'm to migrate a extent git repository to a new svn repository,.
I'm follow this steps: http://sandrotosi.blogspot.com/2010/02/migrate-git-repo-to-svn-one.html

The problem is, when I run the command

```
git svn dcommit
```

The error message is:

```
digger$ git svn dcommit
Committing to http://repository_url_path/trunk ...
A   .gitmodules
A   vendor/rails
6ce13429cbc1359d85e1dc99c84561840e89d455 doesn't exist in the repository at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4277
Failed to read object 6ce13429cbc1359d85e1dc99c84561840e89d455 at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 558
```

How can'i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your git repo is incomplete? Or maybe you're using submodules or something like that? What does `git show 6ce13429cbc1359d85e1dc99c84561840e89d455` say ?

Comment: You should check your repo with `git fsck`.

Comment: What version of git are you running? The line-numbers aren't even close to match with my version (1.7.4)...

Comment: I'm using git version 1.6.5.3. When I run git show 6ce13429cbc1359d85e1dc99c84561840e89d455 the console show: fatal: bad object 6ce13429cbc1359d85e1dc99c84561840e89d455

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016324/git-svn-dcommit-not-work it is because of git submodule usage.

Comment: freespace - your comment is recursive!

Comment: Damn, I was already stuck in the loop...

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-svn - #object# doesn't exist in the repository at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4706](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771033/git-svn-object-doesnt-exist-in-the-repository-at-opt-local-libexec-git-cor)

Answer (score 4):

You are using submodules with git-svn.

You can rewrite git history to remove it http://de-co-de.blogspot.com/2009/02/git-svn-and-submodules.html :

```
$ git tag bad mywork~5
$ git checkout bad
$ # make changes here and update the index
$ git commit --amend
$ git rebase --onto HEAD bad mywork
```

Or easier http://ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2011/06/quick-trip-panic-room :

```
$ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch vendor/rails'
```