# svn: E000002: Commit failed

Tags: git, svn, version-control, wordpress, git-svn

I'm trying to publish my Wordpresss plugin to the svn repository they assigned me. I use `git` (not svn) so I'm trying to use git-svn to but I'm getting the following error when I try to push my local git repo using [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn):

```
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-github-pipeline/trunk ...
    A   .bowerrc
    A   composer.json
    A   composer.lock
   ...
    A   vendor/guzzle/guzzle
b3f5050cb6270c7a728a0b74ac2de50a262b3e02 doesn't exist in the repository at /usr/local/git/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN/Editor.pm line 401.
Failed to read object b3f5050cb6270c7a728a0b74ac2de50a262b3e02 at /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 1011.
```

I've done a lot of searching (see "Other Resources" below) and I understand this problem commonly results from the use of submodules in conjunction with `git svn`. I did have a submodule at one point, but I committed the files and removed `.gitmodules` using `git filter-branch` [described here](http://www.ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2011/06/quick-trip-panic-room) but the problem persisted. So I searched more and it seems that using composer and/or bower can cause the same problem.

<del>I haven't tried removing `vendor/` from my .gitignore and committing all the 3rd party libraries... I have a hunch that might work, but even if it does it's not a sustainable long-term solution.</del>

Is there a way to tell git-svn to ignore my .gitignore and upload all the `vendor/ files?`. Or is there another way to avoid committing ALL my dependancies into the repo? Or is this a different problem than what I think? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**
I removed `vendor/**` from my `.gitignore` and committed the dependencies in my local repository (but didn't push to origin). But I got the exact same error!

**UPDATE 2**
I copied all the files into a new directory and tried to do a basic svn commit. No submodules. All vendor/ files included. And I get another error:

```
$ svn ci -m 'Adding version 1.0 files'
Sending        trunk/.gitignore
Adding         trunk/README.md
...
Adding         trunk/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/utils/wp-completion.bash
Adding         trunk/wp-cli.yml
Adding         trunk/wp-github-pipeline.php
Transmitting file data .............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................svn: E000002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000002: Can't open file '/home/svn/repos/wp-plugins/db/transactions/1232700-rw56.txn/props': No such file or directory
```

I tried `svn cleanup` and the same thing happened.

**UPDATE 3**
I tried starting over from scratch and the SAME error happens. Here is the exact sequence of commands:

```
$ mkdir pipeline_svn2
$ svn co http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-github-pipeline pipeline_svn2
$ cd pipeline_svn2

[ copied all files into pipeline_svn2/ ]

$ svn add trunk/*
$ svn ci -m 'Adding v1.0 files'

[ lots of these... ]
Adding         trunk/wp-github-pipeline.php
Transmitting file data ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................svn: E000002: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E000002: Can't open file '/home/svn/repos/wp-plugins/db/transactions/1233755-rx30.txn/props': No such file or directory
```

It's making me think something is screwed up on the server.

**Other Resources**

- [git-svn - #object# doesn't exist in the repository at /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-svn line 4706](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771033/git-svn-object-doesnt-exist-in-the-repository-at-opt-local-libexec-git-cor)
- http://www.ignoredbydinosaurs.com/2011/06/quick-trip-panic-room
- http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/rails2-upgrade-git-svn-workflow-warts/
- http://blog.winding-lines.com/2009/02/git-svn-and-submodules.html
- [Pushing an existing git repository to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661018/pushing-an-existing-git-repository-to-svn)
- http://flavio.castelli.name/2007/09/04/howto_use_git_with_svn/

Comment: Starting from scratch, before attempting `dcommit` can you try [**this**](http://blog.easy-designs.net/archives/subtree-merge-as-an-alternative-to-submodules-with-git-svn/) to "fix" the git sub-modules problem with svn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of this...

After speaking with the Wordpress plugin team, they recommended that I try using the `https:` protocol (instead of `http:`):

> Instead of using http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-github-pipeline as your plugin SVN URL, try using https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-github-pipeline instead.
>
> Sometimes, proxies and various routers and other types of traffic modifiers interfere with SVN traffic, for some people. Using https allows for end-to-end encryption, preventing most of these from altering the traffic and causing these sorts of problems.

I made the change with `svn relocate` and it still didn't work, but it gave a more verbose error message. So I did some more research and found [this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/svn-access-to-is-forbidden?replies=9) which suggests that my new error might be related to permissions/authentication.

So on a hunch, I re-authenticated after removing the file in `~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple` and did a brand new `svn co` and started from scratch, using `https:` and then it *finally worked*!

I'm not sure if the problem was related to http-->https redirection or a problem with authentication (I have two Wordpress.org accounts).

Comment: Completely don't understand how HTTPS vs HTTP access could solve this. Any details from WordPress plug-in team?

Comment: @bahrep I added the direct quote above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. In one commit, I accidently replaced a symlink by a submodule. There were two problems:

1. changing the type of something is not possible in one commit in svn, for example file -> directory, directory -> file, file -> symlink etc.
2. obviously, git submodules is a feature of git and cannot be handlet by git svn

I didn't invest more time in finding out which of these two problems really stopped git svn